# Mouse pointer moving only in 8 directions

Tags: mouse

I am dual-booting Windows 11 and Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. On Windows, mouse works perfectly fine, but on Ubuntu it can move only 8 directions: up, down, left, right and corners.
For example, if I move the mouse in upper direction, and only slightly to the left/right, it will either not move, or move only up.

What can I do to fix this? I tried to check mouse parameters using xinput, but there was nothing related to the movement direction of the mouse.